# shorthand referral to data fields in panda?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm working in pandas and am trying to create some dictionaries to store datafields pertaining to specific unique row values.

Example data:

```
Date, Indicator, Income
01 Jan 2000, 1.01.02 Sales, $400
02 Jan 2000, 1.01.02 Sales, $600
07 July 2000, 3.01.03 Exports, $500
```

Example code:

```
Indicators = df['Indicator'].unique().tolist()
# to create a datafield for each unique indicator under the Indicators heading
I_dict = {I: df.loc[df['Indicator'] == I] for I in Indicators}
```

My problem is that the indicators themselves are really long - they have a code at the beginning to identify them, but I can't figure out how to separate them and still follow this process.

To fix this, I'm using the following: *(where `'3.05.10 Overseas Exports'` is the Indicator)*

```
print(I_dict['3.05.10 Overseas Exports'])
```

I would prefer to label it with '3.05.10' instead.
**Is this possible?** Another problem is that not all the codes are that length – some are '5.02'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe as seen below

```py
df
           Date        Indicator Income
0   01 Jan 2000    1.01.02 Sales   $400
1   02 Jan 2000    1.01.02 Sales   $600
2  07 July 2000  3.01.03 Exports   $500
3   01 Jan 2000     1.01 Sales A   $400
4   02 Jan 2000     1.01 Sales A   $600
5  07 July 2000   3.01 Exports A   $500
```

What you can do is

```py
import re

# this regex captures all the digits and dots. the last dot-digit combination
# is optional
r = re.compile(r"(\d+\.\d+(?:\.\d+)?)")

# create a short indicator
df['ShortInd'] = df.Indicator.map(lambda x: r.search(x).group(0))
df
           Date        Indicator Income ShortInd
0   01 Jan 2000    1.01.02 Sales   $400  1.01.02
1   02 Jan 2000    1.01.02 Sales   $600  1.01.02
2  07 July 2000  3.01.03 Exports   $500  3.01.03
3   01 Jan 2000     1.01 Sales A   $400     1.01
4   02 Jan 2000     1.01 Sales A   $600     1.01
5  07 July 2000   3.01 Exports A   $500     3.01

# create your dictionary
i_dict = {g: sub_df for g, sub_df in df.groupby('ShortInd')}

i_dict.keys()
dict_keys(['1.01', '1.01.02', '3.01', '3.01.03'])

i_dict['1.01']
          Date     Indicator Income ShortInd
3  01 Jan 2000  1.01 Sales A   $400     1.01
4  02 Jan 2000  1.01 Sales A   $600     1.01
```